# Change currency icon block to drop-down list

Tags: php

My client would prefer a currency drop-down list to the currency icon block installed on a 1.5.1 OpenCart theme. I've tried coding it but get the following error:
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ';' in /...file path......
I've pasted the code and used ***before and after the offending line***.

```
<?php 
$a = 0; 
foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
    $thisCurTitle[$a] = $currency['title'];  
    $thisCurCode[$a] = $currency['code']; 

   if ($currency['symbol_left']) { 
      $thisCurSymb[$a] = $currency['symbol_left'];
   } else { 
      $thisCurSymb[$a] = $currency['symbol_right'];
   } 
   $a++;
} 
?>
<select name=”curselect” onchange=”$(‘input[name=\'currency_code\']‘).attr(‘value’, this.options[this.selectedIndex].value).submit(); $(this).parent().parent().submit();”>
***<?php for ($z = 0; $z <= $a – 1; $z++) { ?>***
<?php if ($thisCurCode[$z] == $currency_code) { ?>
<option value=”<?php echo $thisCurCode[$z]; ?>” selected><?php echo $thisCurTitle[$z]; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $thisCurSymb[$z]; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value=”<?php echo $thisCurCode[$z]; ?>”><?php echo $thisCurTitle[$z]; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $thisCurSymb[$z]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: first suggestion would be to not put all your code on one line....

Comment: Make sure the code is formatted and indented so it's readable, then tell us what line number is reported in the error.

Answer (score 1):

`$a – 1` contains something like an m-dash, or whatever it's called. Not a `-` minus sign. This most likely happened because you copy-pasted code that had been through an auto-formatter like some mail programs or word processors.

Comment: +1 for an eagle eye. The curly quotes had me looking for something like that too but I couldn't spot it.

Comment: Actually I just copied it into a console and ran `"–" == "-"`, it returned `false` :p Thanks for the upvote ^_^

Comment: Sorry for incorrectly posting the question. The line generating the error is: <?php for ($z = 0; $z <= $a – 1; $z++) { ?>

Comment: Yes, and that line is what I'm talking about. Also remove all those curly quotes as they will cause problems too.

Answer (score 1):

after 2 hours of work here is my solution

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formcur" id="formcur">
<div id="currency"> 
<?php echo $text_currency; ?>
<?php 
$a = 0; 
foreach ($currencies as $currency) { 
    $thisCurTitle[$a] = $currency['title']; 
    $thisCurCode[$a] = $currency['code']; 
    if ($currency['symbol_left']) { 
        $thisCurSymb[$a] = $currency['symbol_left']; 
    } else { 
        $thisCurSymb[$a] = $currency['symbol_right']; 
    } 
    $a++; 
} 
?>
<select name="curselect" id="curselect" onchange="$('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', document.getElementById('curselect').value); document.forms['formcur'].submit();">
<?php 
for ($z = 0; $z <= $a - 1; $z++) { 
    if ($thisCurCode[$z] == $currency_code) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $thisCurCode[$z]; ?>" selected><?php echo $thisCurTitle[$z]; ?> <?php echo $thisCurSymb[$z]; ?></option>
<?php 
} else { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $thisCurCode[$z]; ?>"><?php echo $thisCurTitle[$z]; ?> <?php echo $thisCurSymb[$z]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $redirect; ?>" />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the value returned in your `if` block is a String?

```
if ($currency['symbol_left']) {
```

Comment: Given that's nowhere near the line the error is on, mind explaining that logic?

Comment: @Kolink The question was edited after I had posted this. The answer still holds.

Comment: Well... your answer was "40 mins ago", and the last question edit was "41 mins ago"...

Comment: @Kolink Quit giving me notifications for puerile responses; Here's what the question looked like when I answered it : http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/86033184-d740-45a2-a94e-2f204ffba90f/view-source

http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9070606/revisions
I'm offering the OP assistance and not here to do shady stuff. Quit the bull.

Comment: @Kolink The original question I submitted my answer to is **Revision [1]** here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9070606/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Had to clean up your code to be able to make any sense of it. You had a load of odd ` chars stick to " and ' and try to keep inside PHP as much as possible.... this is not an answer yet.... I suggest you upload this and identify to us exaclty which line is at fault, I suspect its in the first echo

```
<?php 

$a = 0; 

foreach ($currencies as $currency) 
{
    $thisCurTitle[$a] = $currency['title']; 

    $thisCurCode[$a] = $currency['code']; 

    if ($currency['symbol_left']) 
    { 
        $thisCurSymb[$a] = $currency['symbol_left'];
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $thisCurSymb[$a] = $currency['symbol_right'];
    } 

    $a++;
} 


echo "<select name='curselect' onchange='$('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value’,     this.options[this.selectedIndex].value).submit(); $(this).parent().parent().submit();'>";

for ($z = 0; $z <= $a – 1; $z++) 
{
    if ($thisCurCode[$z] == $currency_code) 
    {
        echo "<option value='".$thisCurCode[$z]."'     selected>".$thisCurTitle[$z]."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$thisCurSymb[$z]."</option>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option value='".$thisCurCode[$z]."'>".$thisCurTitle[$z]."&nbsp;&    nbsp;".$thisCurSymb[$z]."</option>";
    }
    }

    ?>
```

found the problem.....

You have placed a calculation inside the for() statement...

```
$a =10;             // this is to mimic your counter

$a=$a-1;            // do you subtract here


//for ($z = 0; $z <= $a – 1; $z++) // this is the issue.
//for ($z = 0; $z <= ($a – 1); $z++) // doesn't work either.
for($z=0; $z <= $a; $z++)
{
    echo $z." hello</br />";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

cant see any reason why you wouldnt be able to do it the way you tried, my PHP errors in the same way, even encapsulating the subtract in ()... fixes the issue but still bothers me. Rarely use for()...

I hope that fixes your trouble!

Comment: The line generating the error is: for ($z = 0; $z <= $a – 1; $z++)

Comment: see fix ^^ It solves the error, but i'm not 100% happy with the answer.